# stopping an infinite loop with no preset exit condition

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Ok, so the script below is going to run on an RPI3 to monitor Network speed. 
I need a way to stop infinite loop without interrupting the process every cycle.
As of right now, the script won't exit the loop before the program is terminated. That is a huge problem because I need to save it with the `workbook.close()` function.
 Another way to solve this would be to just close the file for each cycle, but as far as I know, you can't edit a xlsx file with `xlsxwriter`. Only write new...

```
import xlsxwriter
import pyspeedtest
import time

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
st = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest()


def testspeed():
    ping = st.ping()
    upload = st.upload()
    download = st.download()
    return ping, upload, download


n = 1
while True:
    p, u, d = testspeed()
    worksheet.write(n, 0, p)
    worksheet.write(n, 1, u)
    worksheet.write(n, 2, d)
    n += 1
    time.sleep(3600)
    #Some user input to break the loop
    #but not hinder the process


workbook.close()
```

ps : it would make me **very** happy if someone could edit the title to something fitting....

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @StephenRauch ya that solves it. 
But in the case that this library did not exist: how would you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your program is running in the foreground in a console, you can interrupt the process with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) provides a convenient way to clean up in that case:

```
with contextlib.closing(xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')) as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    st = pyspeedtest.SpeedTest()

    n = 1
    while True:
        p, u, d = testspeed()
        worksheet.write(n, 0, p)
        worksheet.write(n, 1, u)
        worksheet.write(n, 2, d)
        n += 1
        time.sleep(3600)
        # Just press Control-C when you get tired of waiting,
        # workbook.close() will be called automatically
```